# error in importing project from android 2.3 to 2.2?

Tags: android

I have android project which is written in android 2.3 but when I import in android  2.2 ,Iam receiving an error .could someone possibly tell me ,how to overcome this problem?

Comment: if you can give details of the error, and a proper description of what exactly you are trying to do and how you are doing it, you'll be a lot more likely to get useful answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to project properties then select Android and select 2.2.May solve your problem

Comment: i am not getting any option to change settings of project in project properties.

Comment: Select your project > Right Mouse click > Properties>Android> Android2.2>Ok

Answer (score 0):

DIfferent API versions have changes in their libraries and so something created for 2.2 can be compatible with newer API versions but something made in 2.3 may not be backwards compatible with the previous version. Thus you may need to check what pieces of your code have to be modified if you want to port it to a previous API version.